# Exponential power of sum

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQgc8.jpg)

Hi. I was just wondering if Exponential functions that has a power of sum, can I change it to the a product with both having exponentials in them? This is a little hard for me to explain, so I included a picture together. Is this mathematically accurate ?

Comment: Yes, it's accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And then you can write
the right hand part as

$\begin{array}\\
e^{i\pi(0.8525+n)}
&=e^{0.8525i\pi}e^{i\pi n}\\
&=(\cos(0.8525\pi)+i\sin(0.8525\pi))(\cos(\pi n)+i\sin(\pi n))\\
&=(-1)^n(\cos(0.8525\pi)+i\sin(0.8525\pi))\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $e^{a+b}=e^ae^b$. That is a property of exponents.